# Typescript AMD Module not returning anything

Tags: requirejs, typescript, amd

I am exporting a simple function inside of a "log.ts" file:

```
export function message(s : string) {
    console.log(s);
}
```

This is imported by a file ("MyController.ts") in the same directory:

```
import log = module("./log");
class MyController {

    a : string = "aaa";

    constructor () {
        log.message("hello world");
    }
}
```

When compiled, I get the following JS:

```
define(["require", "exports", "./log"], function(require, exports, __log__) {
    var log = __log__;

    var MyController = (function () {
        function MyController() {
            this.a = "aaa";
            log.message("hello world");
        }
        return MyController;
    })();    
})
//@ sourceMappingURL=MyController.js.map
```

This define function should return MyController. Because it does not, the callback inside this snippet does not get anything for the controller parameter:

```
   require(["MyController"], function (controller) {
                    theRoute.controller = controller;
                    defer.resolve();
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                });
```

I can fix this by manually adding the return inside of the call to define, but this is not a good workaround because the JS is being outputted by the TS compiler.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write:

```
import log = module("./log");
export class MyController { // <--- 'export'
    a : string = "aaa";
    constructor () {
        log.message("hello world");
    }
}
```

And:

```
   require(["MyController"], function (controller) {
     theRoute.controller = new controller.MyController(); // <--
     defer.resolve();
     $rootScope.$apply();
   });
```

Starting in 0.9.x you'll be able to write `export = MyController;` at the bottom of the .ts file to make the class be the top-level exported object.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Is that the only change that is coming to modules in TS 0.9? Thats the only one I could notice in the specification. Would appreicate if you blog about the module changes introduced in 0.9

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Internal modules seem to be the same between 0.8 and 0.9

Comment: Thanks for this. I was stumped as to why my "define" ts class dependencies were being passed to my require function as objects instead of classes (or ES5 functions). Now I see each dependency is wrapped in an object and I have to do arg1.MyClass, for example.